# Error authenticating Github using Travis CI

Tags: bash, git, github, travis-ci, ssh-keygen

I am trying to automate pushing my javadoc for my Minecraft Mod using Travis CI. Travis is building, and uploading to Bintray, as well, but I thought it would be easy to add in the javadoc as well. [This](https://github.com/LousyLynx/On-The-Fly/blob/master/scripts/updateJavadoc) is my script to upload to the repository, and I was using [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/domenic/ec8b0fc8ab45f39403dd) to make it work. To generate the key, I used this command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "mttprvstanddad@gmail.com"
```

I then copied the key from `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into my `deploy_key` file. I also copied it as a deploy key on the repository. Once I did that, I ran this command:

```
travis encrypt-file deploy_key
```

The error I get looks a little something like this:

```
bad decrypt
139975363151520:error:0606506D:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:wrong final block length:evp_enc.c:532:
```

All of the other files and information should be fairly easy to find, it is at [this repository](https://github.com/LousyLynx/On-The-Fly).

Comment: I could not reproduce. I ran the same `ssh-keygen` command and `travis encrypt-file` worked for me

Comment: are you on windows? If yes then [this thread](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4746) suggests that this problem still exists on windows

Comment: Aside from the possibly windows related encrypt/decrypt, it looks like you encrypted and copied your ssh public key ```id_rsa.pub``` and not your private key ```id_rsa```.

Comment: Yes I am using Windows. I am looking for an alternative right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [hansaplast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864609/error-authenticating-github-using-travis-ci?noredirect=1#comment70917800_41864609) for telling me that the issue was related to being one Windows. I setup a Linux virtual machine, and encrypted it there. Now the build is working.